# Is it possible to install Rstudio server on Linux without root access?

Tags: r, linux, rstudio-server

I'm an undergraduate research assistant working on a Linux server without root privilege. I'm trying to install the Rstudio server but the Rstudio website only provides the installation method for sudoers. Is it possible to install it without root access? I'm asking because I'm really not sure if I could get access from the manager. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218545408-Root-requirements-for-RStudio-Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't install it without root access. But there are a couple of things you could do to piece together a solution. Here are two options:

#### Extract the server and run it directly

You have to be root to install packages, so you can't install the .deb/.rpm file yourself. However, you *could* extract the contents of the file to a directory inside your home directory and run RStudio Server from there, by executing the `rserver` program in a regular shell.

Note that this will probably require an afternoon of editing the `rserver.conf` file to tell it where to find the rest of the files in the installation (since it presumes they are installed in `/usr/lib` by default). You can get some inspiration for how to do this here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/conf/rserver-dev.conf

#### Run the desktop version and forward the graphics

The other route is to run RStudio Desktop on the server; we make several builds of RStudio Desktop that are installer-less and can just be unpacked into your home directory. Then run an X11 server on your own computer and an X11 client on the RStudio server, so that the RStudio Desktop instance appears on your computer instead of the server.

Comment: Where can I find the file rserver.conf?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run rserver without root priveliges.

For RStudio 1.4 I patched the following line into `src/cpp/core/LogOptions.cpp`

```
const FilePath kDefaultLogPath = core::system::xdg::userDataDir().completePath("log");
```

Then you need to set the system environment variables to some location read-writeable for the user, like

```
RSTUDIO_CONFIG_DIR=$HOME/.config/rstudio
RSTUDIO_CONFIG_HOME=$HOME/.config/rstudio
RSTUDIO_DATA_HOME=$HOME/.local/share/rstudio
```

And start `rserver` with the option

```
--server-data-dir={directory writeable for user}
--server-pid-file={file-path creatable for user}
--database-config-file={config-file}
```

With these adjustments it runs for me when I start it as a simple user (no root privileges) with

```
rserver --auth-none=1 --www-frame-origin=same --www-port={port} --www-verify-user-agent=0 --server-data-dir={my-tmp-path} --server-pid-file={my-tmp-path}/rstudio.pid --database-config-file={my-tmp-path}/db.conf}
```

ATTENTION:
But be aware, that anyone who can reach your system and the specified port from the network has access to the running RStudio in his browser and therefore can run any command in the name of the user on your system now.

Comment: For the current version of [LogOptions.cpp](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/main/src/cpp/core/LogOptions.cpp), may I ask where the patch line `const FilePath kDefaultLogPath = ...` should be inserted?

Comment: The problem was fixed by this commit in Nov 24, 2021: 
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/commit/8e9643254b727e8dfbcc458b1be721100723d616